# Timecop is not able to mock date correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, timecop

I am using TimeCop Gem for testing time sensitive test cases. There is one file in the lib directory. It just contains string constants.

Example.

```
module DateStr
   SAMPLE = "Some date #{Date.current}"
end
```

In my cucumber test cases, this part of code does not get mock time. It picks system time. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `DateStr` was loaded, the `SAMPLE` constant was created and assigned the date that was present.

I'd say that this is the wrong use case for constants, since they aren't supposed to change.

EDIT.

I wouldn't use constants for this behaviour. A *hackish* way would be to use lambdas:

```
module DateStr
   SAMPLE = -> {"Some date #{Date.current}"}
end
DateStr::SAMPLE.call # This will evaluate to current date
```

But this is not a good use case, since the value is not *constant* it self, instead for this kind of behaviour you should use a simple class method:

```
module DateStr
   def self.sample
     "Some date #{Date.current}"
   end
end
```

Comment: But then I wont be able to mock it anyway. Module load will always happen before TimeCop mocks Date. Any suggestion here?